# How to identify a specific message in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, retention

As I understand that a Kafka message can be identified by topic, partition and offset. If I add the message along with the topic, partition and offset into my local database, then I can compare this when a new Kafka message received to ensure I won't insert the same message again.

But by default Kafka topic has a retention policy to keep the Kafka messages only for 7 days. After that the messages will be removed.

My question is that after a Kafka message is removed by the retention policy, will the message offset be re-used for new message? If yes then it will be an issue for me to mistreat a new message as an existing message as they held the same offset. Please advise how the offset works for the retention policy and how to handle this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as long as the Kafka cluster is not recreated, a topic will not reuse offsets. It is common to keep the offset stored (e.g. in the database or automatically using consumer groups) to know up to which point a consumer has processed a topic.